# How to get Data In firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[Firebase Database][1]

> how do I get the value from IdPenjual to be a parameter to display Request data in accordance with IdPenjual?
>
> I have firebase database like this

database firebase

```
"Request" : {
"1530686546775" : {
  "alamat" : "ff",
  "nama" : "fafa",
  "noHp" : "12345",
  "produk" : [ {
    "diskon" : "0",
    "harga" : "1000",
    "idPenjual" : "08",
    "jumlah" : "1",
    "namaProduk" : "DOUBLE DELIGHT"
  } ],
  "status" : "0",
  "total" : "Rp1.000"
}
```

> Class OrderStatus

how do I get the value from IdPenjual to be a parameter to display Request data in accordance with IdPenjual?

```
public class OrderStatus extends AppCompatActivity {

RecyclerView recyclerView;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Request, OrderViewHolder> adapter;
FirebaseDatabase database;
DatabaseReference request;

private String userId;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_order_status);

    //Firebase
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    request = database.getReference("Request");

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.listOrders);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    loadOrder(); //mendapatkan data pesanan
}

private void loadOrder() {

    adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Request, OrderViewHolder>(
            Request.class,
            R.layout.order_layout,
            OrderViewHolder.class,
            request

    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(OrderViewHolder viewHolder, Request model, int position) {

            //mendapatkan status pesanan
            viewHolder.txtOrderId.setText(adapter.getRef(position).getKey());
            viewHolder.txtOrderStatus.setText(Common.convertCodeToStatus(model.getStatus()));
            viewHolder.txtOrderAlamat.setText(model.getAlamat());
            viewHolder.txtOrderNoHP.setText(model.getNoHp());

            viewHolder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {
                    //agar tidak eror saat terpencet
                }
            });

        }
    };
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


}
```

}

here the class

```
public class Request {
private String NoHp;
private String Nama;
private String Alamat;
private String Total;
private String Status;
private List<Order> Produk;
private String IdPenjual;

public Request(){

}
public Request(String noHp, String nama, String alamat, String total, List<Order> produk, String idPenjual){
    NoHp = noHp;
    Nama = nama;
    Alamat = alamat;
    Total = total;
    Status = "0";//default 0, 0=Proses, 1=Pengiriman, 2=Terkirim
    Produk = produk;
    IdPenjual = idPenjual;
}


public void setNoHp(String noHp) {
    NoHp = noHp;
}

public String getNoHp() {
    return NoHp;
}

public void setNama(String nama) {
    Nama = nama;
}

public String getNama() {
    return Nama;
}

public String getAlamat() {
    return Alamat;
}

public void setAlamat(String alamat) {
    Alamat = alamat;
}

public void setTotal(String total) {
    Total = total;
}

public String getTotal() {
    return Total;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return Status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    Status = status;
}

public void setProduk(List<Order> produk) { Produk = produk;
}
public List<Order> getProduk() {
    return Produk;
}

public void setIdPenjual(String idPenjual) {
    IdPenjual = idPenjual;
}

public String getIdPenjual() {
    return IdPenjual;
}
```

}

and ViewHolder

```
public class OrderViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnCreateContextMenuListener {

    public TextView txtOrderId, txtOrderStatus, txtOrderNoHP, txtOrderAlamat;

    private ItemClickListener itemClickListener;

    public OrderViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        txtOrderId = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.order_id);
        txtOrderStatus = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.order_status);
        txtOrderNoHP = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.order_nohp);
        txtOrderAlamat = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.order_alamat);


        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);


    }

    public void setItemClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        itemClickListener.onClick(v,getAdapterPosition(),false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

        menu.add(0,0,getAdapterPosition(), "Edit");
        menu.add(0,1,getAdapterPosition(), "Edit");
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void checkForidPenjual(String id) {
    Query filterQuery = FirebaseInstance.getFirebaseDatabase().getReference().child("Request").orderByChild("idPenjual").equalTo(email);
    filterQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists())
            {
                // record found
            }
            else {
                // no record found
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

by this way you will get data from your firebase database based on param.

Comment: take id from record and pass id to this function, for now pass static id and call this function in you on create or any button click event. check that data is coming or not.

Comment: the data is not comming, i check it with Toast and change litle bit code for .equalTo(Common.currentUser.getNoHp()) , the function getNoHp() is working

Comment: ok, cool, if it help you then please accept and upvote answer.

Comment: the produk is list object